# Complete list of data-type(@type) used in google-rich-snippets json-ld

Tags: types, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Is there any complete list of @type in google rich snippets `json-ld`,there are many data-type are used like `Organisation`,`listItem`,`Recipe`,etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google uses (a subset of) the vocabulary Schema.org for their search features.

- All **Schema.org types** are listed on this page:

  http://schema.org/docs/full.html

  (see also my answer about [how to find suitable types/properties](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633))
- All **Google search features** are documented in their Search documentation (see the sidebar):

  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/